# Grails - uninstalling Spring Security Core

Tags: plugins, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

What is the correct way to uninstall spring-security-core plugin completely? I'm working on a Grails app that no longer needs a login and I'd like to remove it.

Even though I have uninstalled it via:

*grails uninstall-plugin spring-security-core*

Plugin [spring-security-core-1.1.3] is installed, but was not found in the application's metadata, do you want to uninstall? [y,n]
My choice doesn't seem to effect anything.

I keep getting message "Configuring Spring Security ..." when starting application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`uninstall-plugin` should work, but you can do it manually. Edit `application.properties` and remove the line for the plugin, then delete the directory under `$HOME/.grails/<grails version>/projects/<your project>/plugins`. Then run `grails clean` to remove any old classes.

In general this will work, as long as the plugin doesn't do any work in its `_Uninstall.groovy` script, which is the case for Spring Security Core (it's empty).

Answer (score 2):

You should also make sure you clean up any references to Spring Security beans that you may have used.  For example, if you are injected springSecurityService into your controllers/services/etc to retrieve the currently logged in user - you will now find missing beans on startup/null pointer exceptions